# Timeline of answer acceptance

Tags: support, timeline

I notice the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316) of an answer does not include when the answer was accepted or un-accepted. Was this intentionally left out or simply overlooked? It seems like as interesting a statistic as the rest, and can help to understand the progression of a thread to know when the acceptance changed from one answer to another.

Comment: SEDE does have the acceptdate: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1367756 but there is no public history of when or if an acceptvote was changed.

Comment: hover the green tick to get the information

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that would be the time of the most recent acceptance. It seems there is no way to see a full history of changes to the acceptance.

Comment: While it might be interesting, since answer acceptance *only* means "it helps *the asker* the most" (despite if it's what the community's votes indicate the best solution or not), what info could be gotten from it? The fact that only a small population of users have ever updated the accept status?